# Adding stylesheet to all pages based on user clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The idea is that there's a settings page on the website that changes the theme universally. So the settings page would contain this link;

```html
<a href="">Click here to enable dark mode</a>
```

Clicking this would then add another stylesheet to every page.

```html
<?php echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='darkmode.css'>"; >
```

That's the idea anyway, the site is built and adding the `darkmode.css` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/darkmode.css">` does then show the dark mode on the page.

I'm open to other ideas such as setting a simple cookie and only having the stylesheet active if true. I don't want a toggle on every page because it would mean manually editing all of them and it's only to be available to some users.

I assume a variable would have to be set to true on the settings page but it needs to carry across the whole site so

```html
<?php
if ($darkmode = $true)
  echo "<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/darkmode.css">";
?>
```

I'd assume something like that would need to be added to every page and then just echo the style if it is true?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

`UPDATE 1`

None of this code works but it's just as an example. An admin would select a checkbox and if the box was ticked the page would read the file for yes/no and then echo the link to the additional stylesheet.

```html
<form action="preference.php" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" id="preference" name="preference">
 </form>

<?php
$preference = $_POST["preference"];
$file = fopen("./preference.html","w");
fwrite($file, $preference);
fclose($file);
?>

<?php
echo readfile("http://example.com/admin/preference.html"); ?>
```

`Update 2`
[image: Flow]

That's what should happen.
`1` User turns dark mode on.
`2` Dark mode is stored.
`3` Each page checks and then uses PHP echo for the stylesheet if dark mode is true.

`Update 3`

```html
<form action="preference.php" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" id="preference" name="preference">
 <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" placeholder="Update Preference">
 </form>
 
 

<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['darkmode'])) {
   if ($_COOKIE['darkmode'] == "true") {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://example.com/admin/darkmode.css">';
   }
   else {
   echo '<!--Not Enabled-->';
   }
   }
?>
```

I've added code for the form that would update the preference and the echo function to be added to every page. I just need to be able to save this to a cookie.

`Update 4`

Settings Page:

```html
<form action="preference.php" method="post">
 <input type="checkbox" id="preference" name="preference">
 <input type="submit" id="update" name="update" placeholder="Update Preference">
 </form>
```

Preference.php:

```html
<?php
if (isset($_POST['preference']) {
  // If a checkbox is checked in the form, set a cookie
  setcookie('isDarkMode', '1');
} else {
  // Otherwise -- delete cookie
  setcookie('isDarkMode', '', time() - 3600);
}
?>
```

Added to every page:

```html
<? if (isset($_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) && $_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) { ?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://example.com/stylesheet.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://example.com/darkmode.css'>
  <? } else { ?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://example.com/stylesheet.css'>
  <? } ?>
```

The preference page shows a 500 error when the form is submitted. Any ideas why this may be?

Comment: What `if ($darkmode)` or `if ($darkmode == true)`?..

Comment: That's what I'm not sure about @Arfeo. I need the user to enable it on one page but this has to be stored somewhere so the individual pages can check if it is enabled.

Comment: Anyway, `if ($darkmode = $true)` statement is wrong.

Comment: I know, @Arfeo. I'm asking for a starting point. That was a loose example of what I think may be needed.

Comment: So, if you really know that the statement above is wrong, then try to use cookies or session to store the darkmode state. And check for this at the very beginning of each page rendered. For example, put the check in a header file.

Comment: Yes, I knew it was wrong, it was more to show how I'd expect it to work, I've added more to the question. Is there anywhere you can point me to or are you going to submit an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `preference.php`:

```php
<?
if (isset($_POST['preference'])) {
  // If a checkbox is checked in the form, set a cookie
  setcookie('isDarkMode', '1');
} else {
  // Otherwise -- delete cookie
  setcookie('isDarkMode', '', time() - 3600);
}
```

In a header file for each page:

```html
<html>
<head>
  ...
  <? if (isset($_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) && $_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) { ?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='darkmode.css'>
  <? } else { ?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='normal.css'>
  <? } ?>
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: This is throwing a 500 error on the 'process.php' page

Comment: Can you show the error message from the web server log? @EdgeDeveloper

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/username/domains/mexample.com/public_html/admin/preference.php on line 36 Line 36 is `if (isset($_POST['preference']) {`. Removing the '}' leads to a T String error on `setcookie('isDarkMode', '1');`

Comment: Ah yeah, updated the answer. Missed `)` after if statement, sorry, typo. @EdgeDeveloper

Comment: No need to apologise for the typo. That works now but the dark mode is always enabled, even before setting the cookie on that page. It's an add on so in `update 4` I've got it with both stylesheets. Not sure why It's always showing both.

Comment: isDarkMode does get added to the browser and can be turned off and then the cookie is removed. It just doesn't do anything on the page, it's getting close though.

Comment: Even if I clear cookies & in other browsers. The snippet to be added to every page just adds the one sheet. I've added `<? if (isset($_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) && $_COOKIE['isDarkMode']) { ?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://example.com/stylesheet.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://example.com/admin/darkmode.css'>
  <? } else { ?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://example.com/stylesheet.css'>`

Comment: maybe you'd share the actual page with the defect? it's quite uneasy to catch bugs with eyes shut. @EdgeDeveloper

Comment: I've managed to emulate it on [link](http://http://darkmode.16mb.com) and it works there, I'll try to replicate on the main site.

Comment: I've updated it to match the file tree of the original site. Could you try it again please? I've left the [file trees](http://darkmode.16mb.com/admin/) open so you can see the structure.

Comment: You can [download](http://darkmode.16mb.com/wholesite.zip) the entire site to see where the issue lies :)

Comment: Yeah, found the issue @Arfeo. It works on all pages within `/admin` but doesn't work on pages outside of that. It needs to work on the whole site.

Comment: @EdgeDeveloper have you fixed the issue or do you still need some help?

Comment: It's fixed now. Not an ideal solution but you have to have `preference.php` within `public_html` for it to affect the whole site. Thank you.